# If $X$ $\times$ $Y$ is path connected so is $X$ $\times$ $Y$ - $(x_0,y_0)$ for some $(x_0,y_0)$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I want to prove the following

> Let $X$ $\times$ $Y$ be path-connected show that $X$ $\times$ $Y$ $\setminus$ $(x_0,y_0)$ is still path connected for some point $(x_0,y_0)$

My attempt was by considering the infinite tangents that can be drawn for each point so that it is possible to construct a path without intersecting $(x_0,y_0)$ (by drawing perpendicular if $(x_0,y_0)$ is directly in the way of the two points)
This seems to work for $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I don't know about arbitrary product spaces

But this does not sound rigorous enough is this idea/sketch even correct, is there a more rigorous way to solve this?

Any ideas or hints are appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: The $x$-axis is path-connected but removing a point disconnects it.  If this is a published problem, did you leave off some assumptions?

Comment: I suggest looking at the example $X=\mathbb{R}, Y=\{0\}$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven is it disconnected? Because if we remove a point $(x,0)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ from $(\mathbb{R},0)$ we get $\mathbb{R}$ minus a point which is disconnected? And we have to remove zero from $Y$ since it is the only choice

Comment: Exactly. In fact it is the just the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as Brian Moehring wrote before me (which unfortunately did not see while typing). Thus, you need some more assumptions to make the statement true.

Comment: Talking about infinite tangents or just tangents at all make no sense in an arbitrary topological space.  Even in $\mathbb{R}^2$ your approach makes no sense, as path connectedness is defined in terms of continuous paths, which are not differentiable in general, so there is no notion of tangent.

Comment: @PatrickR Maybe not tangents but there are infinite lines going through a single point right?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be path-connected, and suppose that $X$ and $Y$ each have **at least two elements**. Show that $Z=X\times Y-\{(x,y)\}$ is path-connected.

My guess is that this is the actual question.

The answer is easy:

$\\$

Notice that every set of the form $X\times \{y'\}$ or $\{x'\}\times Y$ is path-connected, for $x'\neq x$ and $y' \neq y$.

Let's say you want to connect $(b,c),(d,e)\in Z$ by a path. I will deal with one of the cases and you can verify the rest.

If $b,d\neq x$ and $c,e\neq y$, then connect $(b,c)$ to $(d,c)$ and then connect $(d,c)$ to $(d,e)$.

Comment: I think I had this in mind while asking could you please tell how this is different from the one I asked (check the comments on the question) because this seems to work and that does not

Comment: Are $y'$ and $x'$ in $Y$ and $X$ respectively?

Comment: Also when $x'$ = $x$ does it happen that $x$ $\times$ $Y$ - $(x,y)$ and then we get the disconnected version of $Y$ because $x$ from $X$ and $x$ from $(x,y)$ cancel each other? (I don't get how removing a point from Y will guarantee disconnection or maybe it does not work like that)

Comment: Also when $x'$ = $x$ does it happen that $x$ $\times$ $Y$ - $(x,y)$ and then we get the disconnected version of $Y$ because $x$ from $X$ and $x$ from $(x,y)$ cancel each other? (I don't get how removing a point from Y will guarantee disconnection or maybe it does not work like that. Does it become like the one I was asking and so those two are different things?)